# Netbeans - Selecting Create/Update Test on a single java file creates two Test files

Tags: java, unit-testing, netbeans, junit

**NOTE:** I do have a solution for this.  It has happened to me a few times in my project as I inherited the issues, and want to share the findings here in case someone runs into a similar issue.

**Issue/Problem:**
I have a module in a Maven project that I'm trying to create Unit tests for in NetBeans v 8.2.

The image below shows the file (the one selected) that I'm trying to create a test file for.

[image]

I right click on the file and select **Tools->Create/Update Tests**.

[image]

When that's done I get two test files as shown below.  You can see a **test.java.com** package within the source packages with a test file created, and then you can see a **Test Packages** folder with test file also created there.

[image]

When I delete one of those files or folders, the other file (within the Source Packages or Test Packages) gets deleted as well.

Answer (score 0):

I realized this was an issue with the maven folder structure of this project.

The initial creator of this module didn't follow the **src/main/java** maven folder structure.

So initially I refactored the existing packages to have **main/java** within the Sources Package.  Notice the package names now have the **main.java** prefixed to it.

[image]

I then added these lines in the pom file:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
 </build>
```

As soon as you save that, the package structure changes in the Projects explorer/window.  Notice now how the **main.java** isn't shown on the package list:

[image]

Now when I select **Tools->Create/Update Test** a single test file and package is created, under the Test Packages folder (no more duplicate test folder appears under the Source Packages folder).

[image]